# VLC player can not support m4v files

Tags: vlc

I am an advanced user of Ubuntu, and I made a script file for TunesViewer to make it work, and it can download all most all videos, and it uses vlc player but iy can not show the file *.m4v, and the file is a unidentified file called 'undf' it says:

> No suitable decoder module: VLC does not support the audio or video
>   format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

and it shows a window with errors. when I click close it says:

> Your input can't be opened: VLC is usable to open Mrd
>   'http://a45.v.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/081/Video/v4/85/54/f1/8554f106-6e77-8264-0bcb-e679609e8e3d/mzvf_5091800164576836550.640x480.h264lc.D2.p.m4c'.
>   Check the log for details.

and than it downloads the file but can not display it, and are there any other players that support this file type? Can some one please help.

Comment: The site says:
The requested URL /Video/v4/85/54/f1/8554f106-6e77-8264-0bcb-e679609e8e3d/mzvf_5091800164576836550.640x480.h264lc.D2.p.m4c was not found on this server.

Comment: Could you possibly add the output of [mediainfo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mediainfo/) for this file?

Comment: Where is that link coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Well, running VLC from a terminal gives a 404 error, meaning the file is not found, but this is with a .M4C extension! Changing to a .M4V, I have a black screen with controls, apparently to play a 30 seconds file... but it doesn't play anything!

My guess is the file is corrupted or not valid! I tried to open it via TunesViewer and it gives me - .M4C or .M4V, same error -

```
Download Error: timed out
```

and when you download it via TV and then open it (it calls 'totem') you get the error

```
the stream is encrypted and decryption is not supported
```

Are you able to open it - the file or the stream - one way or another?

Here is the info requested by @LiveWireBT :

> General
>   Complete name                            :  mzvf_5091800164576836550.640x480.h264lc.D2.p.m4v
>   Format                                   : MPEG-4
>   Codec ID                                 : M4V
>   File size                                : 3.99 MiB
>   Duration                                 : 30s 0ms
>   Overall bit rate                         : 1 116 Kbps
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>
> Video
>   ID                                       : 1
>   Format                                   : AVC
>   Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
>   Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
>   Format settings, CABAC                   : No
>   Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
>   Codec ID                                 : avc1
>   Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
>   Duration                                 : 30s 0ms
>   Source duration                          : 31s 615ms
>   Bit rate                                 : 927 Kbps
>   Width                                    : 640 pixels
>   Height                                   : 480 pixels
>   Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
>   Frame rate mode                          : Constant
>   Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
>   Color space                              : YUV
>   Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
>   Bit depth                                : 8 bits
>   Scan type                                : Progressive
>   Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.126
>   Stream size                              : 3.31 MiB (83%)
>   Source stream size                       : 3.52 MiB (88%)
>   Language                                 : English
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>   Color primaries                          : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M
>   Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709-5, BT.1361
>   Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M
>
> Audio
>   ID                                       : 2
>   Format                                   : AAC
>   Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
>   Format profile                           : LC
>   Codec ID                                 : 40
>   Duration                                 : 30s 0ms
>   Source duration                          : 30s 23ms
>   Bit rate mode                            : Constant
>   Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
>   Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
>   Channel positions                        : Front: L R
>   Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
>   Compression mode                         : Lossy
>   Delay relative to video                  : -1s 300ms
>   Stream size                              : 453 KiB (11%)
>   Source stream size                       : 453 KiB (11%)
>   Language                                 : English
>   Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>   Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-01-09 06:31:37
>   Encryption                               : iTunes

... but after a quick search and it looks like VLC can't decrypt iTunes protection, hence the message @Michael gets!

Comment: Not able to find the file, and don't know if am able open it, and stream it but I can stream some of the movies.

Comment: You can stream from your script in TV? Or on a Winbox with iTunes? Never used iTunes, just tried and couldn't find a way to open an URL...

Comment: The problem is that it is a unidentified format which probely is't there, and no I have not tried this you said.

Answer (score 1):

The file can indeed be downloaded by changing the file extension, so [this is the correct link](http://a45.v.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/081/Video/v4/85/54/f1/8554f106-6e77-8264-0bcb-e679609e8e3d/mzvf_5091800164576836550.640x480.h264lc.D2.p.m4v). However MPlayer identifies the file as encumbered with DRM protection:

```
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (drms / 0x736D7264), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-09 06:31:37
  handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream #0:1(eng): Video: none (drmi / 0x696D7264), 640x480, 932 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-01-09 06:31:37
  handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
```

See the drms and drmi labels in there? IMHO it is best to avoid these type of files and the technology that produces them....

Comment: Really? What iTunesU podcasts use DRM? iTunes music even doesn't have DRM last I heard.

Comment: Well, this one is certainly drm encumbered. I don't know if this is standard for iTunes...

Comment: Hi. Are there any way to get those file decrypted have the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, under Linux...